# Copying a dynamic array and deleting the original using an overloaded operator

Tags: c++, arrays, object, dynamic, operator-overloading

I am creating a class that will keep track of students. In this class, I use an overloaded = to copy these student objects. To track their classes, I use a dynamic array. The array copies just fine; however, when clearing the variables of a student object, any object that had copied from it before also has their array wiped. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;                //Name
    string* classList = NULL;   //Empty array to store class names in
    int numClasses = 0;         //Number of classes

public:
    void InputData()
    {
        cout << "Enter student name: " << endl;                         //Input Name
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter number of classes: " << endl;                    //Input classes
        cin >> numClasses;

        classList = new string[numClasses];                             //Define array size
        for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++)                            //For every spot in array, name class
        {
            cout << "Enter name of class " << (i + 1) << ":" << endl;   //Name class
            cin >> classList[i];
        }

    };

    void OutputData()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;                               //Output data
        cout << "Number of Classes: " << numClasses << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++)                            //Cycle through and output classes
        {
            cout << "Class " << i << ": " << classList[i] << endl;
        }
    };

    void ResetClasses()
    {
        name = "";
        delete[] classList;         //Free Memory
        classList = NULL;           //Clear array
        numClasses = 0;
    };

    Student operator =(Student& student)                //Overload =
    {
        this->name = student.name;
        this->classList = student.classList;
        this->numClasses = student.numClasses;
        return *this;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Student s1, s2;

    s1.InputData();               // Input data for student 1
    cout << "Student 1's data:" << endl;
    s1.OutputData();              // Output data for student 1

    s2 = s1;
    cout << "Student 2's data after assignment from student 1:" << endl;
    s2.OutputData();              // Should output same data as for student 1

    s1.ResetClasses();
    cout << "Student 1's data after reset:" << endl;
    s1.OutputData();              // Should have no classes

    cout << "Student 2's data, should still have original classes:" << endl;
    s2.OutputData();              // Should still have original classes
}
```

The main offenders almost certainly being either of these two

```
        void ResetClasses()
        {
            name = "";
            delete[] classList;         //Free Memory
            classList = NULL;           //Clear array
            numClasses = 0;
        };

        Student operator =(Student& student)                //Overload =
        {
            this->name = student.name;
            this->classList = student.classList;
            this->numClasses = student.numClasses;
            return *this;
        };
```

The output for a program is:

```
Enter student name:
ERIC
Enter number of classes:
2
Enter name of class 1:
C++
Enter name of class 2:
C
Student 1's data:
Name: ERIC
Number of Classes: 2
Class 0: C++
Class 1: C
Student 2's data after assignment from student 1:
Name: ERIC
Number of Classes: 2
Class 0: C++
Class 1: C
Student 1's data after reset:
Name:
Number of Classes: 0
Student 2's data, should still have original classes:
Name: ERIC
Number of Classes: 2
Class 0:
Class 1:
```

What could I be doing wrong to cause this?

Comment: use vector instead of raw pointer and you'll get rid of your problem. Currently you have 2 objects with same pointer.

Comment: Stop the madness and use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: In case 2 comments already saying so isn't sufficient, you should use a `vector<string>`. Not raw arrays and raw pointers and stuff.

Comment: this->classList = student.classList; is wrong. Please create a deep copy of classlist. The problem with current solution is that when you  reset the class, it will free the memory, but the same pointer is being used by another class. That is why you need deep copy. Also the other mistake not related to crash is  that operator= should return ref, i.e student& and not student. But as others mentioned, use vectors

Comment: To correct all of the issues with your code, there are major parts missing from your code (such as pointed out by @SamVarshavchik).  IMO it is better to [see a small example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b1eaa1bfd7c6c52) of these operations and what you are missing..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of the class list, or both student objects will have a field that points to the same location in memory.

Freeing one of these fields will cause the other one to also be freed.

In your copy constructor and assignment operator, **create a new array of the same size for the new object**, and then copy each of the elements to the new object.

Comment: Or simply use what was already implemented - `std::vector<std::string>` like @ArtemyVysotsky suggested.

Comment: That would definitely be the better solution, but I'll leave this answer here because it explains the problem the OP was having initially.

Comment: Don't use `memcpy` -- it won't work with `std::string` as the type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Student operator =(Student& student)
```

The assignment operator should take a `const` reference parameter. The assignment operator should also return a reference, and not a value.

This class is also missing a copy constructor.

In the assignment operator:

```
this->classList = student.classList;
```

This is a plain pointer. For starters, this is a memory leak. The previous pointer (if there is one) gets lost, and its allocated memory gets leaked.

Now you have two instances of your class with the same `classList` pointer. Consequently, when the `resetClasses()` method gets called on one of those classes, it'll be deleted, and since the other instance of the class has the same pointer, it's now pointing to deleted memory.

Your assignment operator must properly delete the existing array, if there is one, and clone the array held in the instance being assigned from, if there is one. Most of this would also apply to the copy constructor that you must implement.

This class is also missing a destructor, which will cause another memory leak.

You have all of these multiple fundamental problems with your class. You must fix all of them in order for your class to work correctly. You must implement a proper copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, that correctly clone, copy, and destroy instances of the data held by your class.

It appears that you haven't yet learned how to use containers and smart pointers, and the point of your excersize if for you to learn how to properly keep track of allocated memory, avoid memory corruption and memory leaks. That is obviously an important skill to learn; but once you've figured all of this out, and your class works correctly, you'll simply replace your pointers by a `std::vector`, and not worry about it any more.